# Change selected option in select

Tags: angular

I want to change selected option in `select` after click on button

**view.html** file

```
<select class="language-selector">
  <option *ngFor="let language of outputLanguageList" 
  value="{{language.shortName}}" >{{language.languageName}}</option>
</select>

<button (click)="changeLanguage()">PL-EN</button>
```

**component.ts** file

```
outputLanguageList:TranslateLanguage[]=[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.outputLanguageList.push({languageName:"Polski",shortName:"pl"});
    this.outputLanguageList.push({languageName:"Angielski",shortName:"en"});
    this.outputLanguageList.push({languageName:"Hiszpański",shortName:"es"});
    this.outputLanguageList.push({languageName:"Niemiecki",shortName:"de"});
    this.outputLanguageList.push({languageName:"Rosyjski",shortName:"ru"});
    this.outputLanguageList.push({languageName:"Ukraiński",shortName:"ua"});
    this.outputLanguageList.push({languageName:"Słowacki",shortName:"sk"});  
}

changeLanguage(){
    //code that will change the selected option in selectbox
}
```

It is possible make this in Angular?

I try do something like this:

```
changeLanguage(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document:Document){
    document.getElementById("asda").value("Polski");
}
```

But i got error: *Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`ngModel` directive](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#setup-in-template-driven-forms) to update the value (either from the UI, or from the `.ts` file):

```html
<select class="language-selector" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage">
  <option *ngFor="let language of outputLanguageList" 
  value="{{language.shortName}}" >{{language.languageName}}</option>
</select>

<button (click)="changeLanguage()">PL-EN</button>
```

In the `.ts` file you need to declare the `selectedLanguage` property and give it an initial value:

```
public selectedLanguage: string | null = null;
```

In your `changeLanguageMethod` you only need this:

```
changeLanguage(){
  this.selectedLanguage = "Polski";
}
```

The rest of your code can stay as it is.